# realloc int pointer present in a structure [C]

Tags: c, structure, realloc

I want to malloc an integer pointer present inside a structure.

If in future I need to expand the array, I use realloc.

something like this:

```
typedef struct {
   int *temp,count
}foo;

main()
{
    foo *fake = (foo*)malloc(1*sizeof(foo));
    fake.count = 0;

    ++(fake.count);
    fake.temp = (int*)malloc((fake.count)*sizeof(int));

    /* I do something */

    /*now i want to realloc "temp" to ++(fake.count) */
```

Is this way of doing that correct?

```
    ++(fake.count);
    fake.temp = (int*)realloc(fake.temp,(fake.count)*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: it should be like `fake->count` `fake->temp` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, yes.

However, you should make sure that your code survives possible errors in `realloc`, like so:

```
int * p = realloc(fake->temp, (fake->count + 1) * sizeof(int));
if (p) { fake->temp = p; ++fake->count; }
else   { /* error! But fake was untouched. */ }
```

Also, you should say `int main(void)` for your main function declaration. Finally, you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc`, since a `void*` is implicitly convertible to any other object pointer.

One more: Your coding style is really difficult for others to read. I'd write the struct definition like this:

```
typedef struct foo_
{
    int * temp;
    int   count;
} foo;
```

And even one more: Do you need to allocate `fake` dynamically? If not, an automatic variable `foo fake;` may be easier to maintain. In any event, if you do want to allocate it dynamically, don't cast and don't repeat the type, like so:

```
foo * fake = malloc(sizeof *fake);
// or:       calloc(1, sizeof *fake);      // this will zero out the memory
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. 

You mean to say that I should use another pointer which is "p" in your case to reallocate "fake.temp" and later on if the reallocation succeeds, make "fake.temp" hold the reallocate memory of "p".

If i don't do it this way, like using another int pointer, will it give me segmentation faults in future if I try to access the reallocated memory or initially malloced memory??

Comment: @sam32: not a segmentation fault, but the result of `realloc` may be `NULL`, and if you overwrite your original pointer immediately, you can never again reach the original allocation. Once `realloc` returns a non-null pointer, it's safe to use that.

Comment: I do need to allocate it dynamically. I didn't really get your point that "don't cast and don't repeat the type".  Can you please elaborate on this.Thanks!

Comment: @sam32: My final code line with `malloc` only contains the name of the type (i.e. "`foo`") *once*, not three times as in your code. And there's no cast.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to cast the return value from `malloc` or `realloc` in a C program.
2. Don't directly assign the result of your `realloc` call to the same variable.  If it fails, you'll leak the original allocation.  Do something like this instead:

   ```
   void *err = realloc(pointer, newSize);
   if (err != NULL)
   {
       pointer = err;
   }
   ```
3. Nitpick - multiplying by 1 looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to say if it will be **OK** to do `realloc` that way without knowing what is `I do something`. But you can start with this....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
 int *temp,count;
 }foo;

extern char etext, edata, end;
int main()
{
   printf("Heap before first malloc %p\n", sbrk(0));

   foo *fake = malloc(1*sizeof(foo));

   printf("heap after first malloc %p\n", sbrk(0));

   fake->count = 0;
   ++(fake->count);
   fake->temp = malloc((fake->count)*sizeof(int));
   printf("heap after second malloc %p\n", sbrk(0));

   fake->count += 2;
   fake->temp = realloc(fake->temp, (fake->count) * sizeof(int));
   printf("count %d\n", fake->count);

   printf("heap after realloc %p\n", sbrk(0));
   printf("program text segment(etext)      %10p\n", &etext);
   printf("initialized data segment(edata)  %10p\n", &edata);
   printf("uninitialized data segment (end) %10p\n", &end);

   return 0;
}
```

This will output your heap addresses also.

```
Heap before first malloc 0x239b000
heap after first malloc 0x23bc000
heap after second malloc 0x23bc000
count 3
heap after realloc 0x23bc000
program text segment(etext)        0x400816
initialized data segment(edata)    0x600bc4
uninitialized data segment (end)   0x600bd8
```

1. You don't need a cast for `malloc()`.
2. Considering `calloc()` to clear out your memory. As you are reallocating, you can get wrongly initialized memory block. (like recently free'd blocks).
3. Always check the return value of `realloc()` before using it. chance of failed `realloc()` is pretty high then `malloc()`.